# Create 5 min bars out of 1 min bars in R

Tags: r, currency, price, trading, stocks

I have these data

```
  Open   High   Low    Close
1 6709.0 6709.5 6703.5 6705.0
2 6705.0 6710.5 6705.0 6710.0
3 6710.5 6713.5 6710.5 6713.5
4 6713.5 6713.5 6711.5 6712.0
5 6712.5 6715.0 6712.5 6714.0
6 6714.0 6716.0 6713.5 6716.0
```

which are `OHLC` prices of `1` minute bars. I want to find `OHLC` of 5 minute bars.
`Open` and `Close` are easy, but I don't know how to do `High` and `Low`.

I need to find the `maximum/minimum` values in a subset of the data.
So first I need to find `max(data[1:5,2])` then `max(data[6:10,2])` and so on. And I need to put the values in a vector called `High`. And for `Low` prices `min(data[1:5,3])`.

I need something like a `for loop` with two variables.

Comment: could you please add your trying code.

Comment: Here

`for(n in x){for (m in y){
     High[i] <- max(data[n:m,2])
     i=i+1
}}`

This would actually work because then I could get the data I wanted by subsetting. But my computer is too slow (the data.frame has 1.5 million rows).

Comment: Actually, your data presents 6 bars so I though to create Group of size 6. Do you need creating Group of 5 bars?

Comment: Yes every row is 1 minute so I need group of 5. The data I put in my post is just the output of `head(data)`.

Comment: Well then you can use my code but the `nrow()` of your dataset must be exactly a multiple of 5. Do you confirm?

Comment: Ok thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how big is your dataset. However, `for loop` would be slow in this case. Personally, I would rather go for an `aggregate` function, specifically, the one already implemented in `Rbase`.

The first thing we have to do is to create an **index** that will **allow us to perform the function on each subgroup**. Each subgroup contains OHLC of 5 minute bars.

Therefore, let's start by reading the data

**read the table**

```
df <- read.table(text = "Open   High    Low  Close
+ 1 6709.0 6709.5 6703.5 6705.0
+ 
+ 2 6705.0 6710.5 6705.0 6710.0
+ 
+ 3 6710.5 6713.5 6710.5 6713.5
+ 
+ 4 6713.5 6713.5 6711.5 6712.0
+ 
+ 5 6712.5 6715.0 6712.5 6714.0")
```

**Increase the size of df** to better simulate the real use case scenario.

```
df <- rbind(df,df,df,df)
```

**Create an index**, first using vector `recycling` and the `cumsum()` function

```
df$group <- c(1,0,0,0,0)
df$group <- cumsum(df$group)
```

Now, finally we can obtain the Min and Max value for each 5 OHLC 5 minute bars and insert them into your final vectors, `High` and `Low`

```
High <- aggregate(High ~ group, data = df, FUN = max)$High
Low <- aggregate(Low ~ group, data = df, FUN = min)$Low
```

---

A faster alternative to aggregate is given by `data.table` package

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
High <- dt[ , max(High), by = group]$V1
Low <- dt[ , min(Low), by = group]$V1
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` based solution which can even work when rows are not multiple of `5` be achieved using `ceiling` to create group.

```
library(dplyr)

# Prepare large data.frame
df_mod <- bind_rows(df,df,df,df,df)

df_mod %>% 
  group_by(grp = ceiling(row_number()/5)) %>%
  summarise(High = max(High), Low = min(Low)) %>%
  select(-grp) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#   grp High    Low
# 1   1 6715 6703.5
# 2   2 6716 6703.5
# 3   3 6716 6703.5
# 4   4 6716 6703.5
# 5   5 6716 6703.5
# 6   6 6716 6705.0
```

**Data**

```
#As provided an example by OP
df <- read.table( text = 
"Open   High   Low    Close
1 6709.0 6709.5 6703.5 6705.0
2 6705.0 6710.5 6705.0 6710.0
3 6710.5 6713.5 6710.5 6713.5
4 6713.5 6713.5 6711.5 6712.0
5 6712.5 6715.0 6712.5 6714.0
6 6714.0 6716.0 6713.5 6716.0",
header = TRUE)
```